# PostGIS location positioning error

Tags: postgis

I'm not sure if this is the right place to be asking this but thought I would give it a shot. I have a world map shapefile imported into PostGIS and a couple of points I have added in a test table. These should be in the UK but they are just off of the coast of Madagascar. I've clearly done something wrong, but looking at the ogrinfo for the two tables, I get:

```
Layer name: countries
Geometry: 3D Multi Polygon
Feature Count: 525
Extent: (-180.000000, -89.999933) - (180.000000, 84.134162)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
FID Column = gid
Geometry Column = geom
scalerank: Integer (2.0)
featurecla: String (32.0)
name: String (254.0)
namealt: String (254.0)
region: String (50.0)
subregion: String (50.0)


INFO: Open of `PG:dbname=g4wd'
      using driver `PostgreSQL' successful.

Layer name: test
Geometry: 3D Point
Feature Count: 2
Extent: (51.009400, -2.638900) - (51.571400, 0.695600)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Geometry Column = location
id: Integer (0.0)
name: String (25.0)
```

So I'm pretty confused as to what I should be checking. Does anybody know what I need to check or do, since all the prj info seems to be correct?

Edit: Added geometry_columns detail - not sure if relevant.

```
g4wd=# select * from geometry_columns;
 f_table_catalog | f_table_schema | f_table_name | f_geometry_column | coord_dimension | srid |     type     
-----------------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+------+--------------
 g4wd            | public         | test         | location          |               2 | 4326 | POINT
 g4wd            | public         | countries    | geom              |               2 | 4326 | MULTIPOLYGON
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinate data for `test` needs to be transposed (Y, X) -> (X, Y), since the axis order for PostGIS (and most other GIS software) is longitude, latitude (not the other way!).

If this data has already been loaded, swap the axis order using this SQL update statement:

```
UPDATE test SET
  location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_Y(location), ST_X(location)), 4326);
```